# How to keep internal/hidden Database connection open when calling JAR?

Tags: java, jdbc, architecture, database-connection

I have to use already developed JAR in order to keep my code running. The JAR provides me with functionality of *transforming file formats* . My code looks something like this:

```
public class Transformer {

 //some fields

 //constructor

 public List<MyFile> tranformFiles(List<MyFile> files){
    JarClassUsed used = new JarClassUsed();
    List<MyFile> data = new ArrayList<>();

    foreach(MyFile file : files){
      data.add(used.TransformFileFormat(file));
    }
    return data;    
 }

}
```

It's working fine, but still very slow. The problem is that the JAR I have to use is making a hidden/internal DB connection call when transforming files (reading predefined configurations). When count is around 100 is acceptable, but I have one case with more than 1000. And as already you guessed is quite problematic.

How can I keep this hidden connection Opened - still DB connections are expensive to create and *Singleton* or *static* sound like good solution. It's not smart to create it for each file that is being processed.  Can I use reflection somehow here?

Comment: If its an internal implementation detail, changing the implementation is the only thing I can think of... You could I guess... use some kinda container managed transactional support, but even then... if they are using raw JDBC... you still may not have the ability to intercept the transaction and reuse the session... I would probably find the tests for that bit of functionality and update it... No tests, try doing something concurrently, but my guess is youll eat up db connections.

Comment: I can't use run in several threads. Database connection timeout is generated. If I run a several executions then I need to have
 a several connections to DB. But DB blocks some of connections
 (a lot of connections from the same IP at the moment). So some of the executions will be failed (several threads) for sure.

Comment: gah let me ask some guys at work... I honestly think a refactor is your solution, but let me ask some people smarter than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we talked about it in the office... it seems the best course of action is to find a library that does the same formats, if thats not possible externalize the configuration and utilize a different library.

I know this does not answer your question in any way... and you probably already knew that... but unless you have the raw source and are allowed to change that jar, the "hidden" connection is something written into the library.

I really wish I had better advice, but I think the best course of action is to investigate other implementations.

If you can list the formats I would be more than happy to assist in this investigation in a different medium.